# Drag and drop images to swap their positions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am trying to implement a photo uploader where the order of photos is important. To do that I have tried to implment a drag and drop mechanism to swap their positions. The issue I am facing is I can not drop images on top of each other. I have to put them in the div sorrouding the images.
Here is the component.html Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input type="file" multiple (change)="onSelectFile($event)" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div
        class="photos-container"
        (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
        (drop)="onDrop($event)"
      >
        <div
          *ngFor="let image of images; index as i"
          class="photo"
          [draggable]="true"
          (dragstart)="onDragStart(i, $event)"
          style="background-color: black;"
        >
          <img [src]="image" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The component.ts code is:

```
onSelectFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.files = event;
      const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
      files.forEach((file: any) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.images.push(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        this.imageChangedEvnt = event;
      });
    }
  }

  onDragStart(index: any, event: any) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("index", index);
  }

  onDragOver(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  onDrop(event: any) {
    const index = event.dataTransfer.getData("index");
    const newIndex = Array.from(event.currentTarget.children).indexOf(
      event.target
    );
    if (newIndex >= 0) {
      const photo = this.images.splice(index, 1)[0];
      this.images.splice(newIndex, 0, photo);
    }
  }
```

Here's the minimum repoducible demo: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-drag-and-drop-8lik8p?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:373-1248)

I tried the code above, but I still can not drop images on top of each other. swapping only works if I put the images in the sorrouding div.

Answer (score 0):

At this line in `onDrop`

```
const newIndex = Array.from(event.currentTarget.children).indexOf(event.target);
```

When you drop an image on top of another, the `event.target` will be `<img...../>`.

In this situation, you are looking for `indexOf` and `<img>` inside an array `<div>` so your `newIndex` is obviously equal to `-1`.

There are two ways to get over

**1. Shouldn't put anything on the drop area** so use `<img>` to handle translate itself. Update **app.component.html** to

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input type="file" multiple (change)="onSelectFile($event)" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div
        class="photos-container"
        (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
        (drop)="onDrop($event)"
        style="
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: black;">
        <img
          [src]="image"
          *ngFor="let image of images; index as i"
          class="photo"
          [draggable]="true"
          (dragstart)="onDragStart(i, $event)"
          style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. More tricky with handle  case.** Update `onDrop` to

```
onDrop(event: any) {
    const index = event.dataTransfer.getData("index");
    let targetElement;
    if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        targetElement = event.target.parentElement;
    } else if (event.target.tagName === "DIV") {
        targetElement = event.target;
    }
    const newIndex = Array.from(event.currentTarget.children).indexOf(
        targetElement
    );
    if (newIndex >= 0) {
        const photo = this.images.splice(index, 1)[0];
        this.images.splice(newIndex, 0, photo);
    }
}
```